# no such file or directory in COPY dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have made the following dockerfile to contain my node js application, the problem is that an error appears when building the dockerfile:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10
 ---> 0d5ae56139bd
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bfc0405d8fa
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker- 
builder803334317/package.json: no such file or directory
```

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

i executed the command:
sudo docker build - < Dockerfile

into my root project folder.

My project folder is simple, like this:

```
-Project
 -app.js
 -Dockerfile
 -package.json
 -package-lock.json
 -README.md
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the Dockerfile-on-stdin syntax

```
sudo docker build - < Dockerfile
```

the build sequence runs in a context that *only* has the Dockerfile, and no other files on disk.

The directory layout you show is pretty typical, and pointing `docker build` at that directory should work better

```
sudo docker build .
```

(This is the same rule as the "Dockerfiles can't access files in parent directories" rule, but instead of giving the current directory as the base directory to Docker, you're giving no directory at all, so it can't even access files in the current directory.)