# COPY failed: file not found in build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am having the following issue when I run `docker build -> DOCKERFILE`

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements_webserver.txt: file does not exist
```

Relevant code from DOCKERFILE:

```
 COPY requirements_webserver.txt /requirements.txt
```

Here is the directory:
[image: Directory]

It wont find either the requirements_webserver.txt or the requirements.txt file.

thanks.

Comment: Run ```docker build .``` in the same directory, ```.``` is for context

Comment: @TelinovDmitri '.' is not a valid option as you need to specify the docker file.

Comment: What is the actual `docker build` command you're running (the command @TelinovDmitri suggests, without a specific `-f` option, would be typical)?  Beyond the `8B2lk.png` file you included in the question, are there other files in the directory?  Is there a `.dockerignore` file, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: @DavidMaze there is no .dockerignore file. The command I am running is: `docker build - < Dockerfile --no-cache`

Comment: The _only_ thing that sends to Docker is the Dockerfile, and not any of the other content.  Use the invocation @TelinovDmitri suggests.  See for example [no such file or directory in COPY dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092091/no-such-file-or-directory-in-copy-dockerfile).